# how to use the awaited type to expect two types of objects

Tags: typescript

I stumbled upon the Awaited utility Type in Typescript and wanted to do a very simple example. Some examples seem to have rust like style and maybe monads. How do I properly implement this here?

```js
type Error = { error_code: number, error_message: string }

export type Response = {

    template_id: number
    user_msg: string
    ssboe: number
    usecs: number
}

export function Heartbeat(usecs: number, ssboe: number):Promise<Response|Error> {

    return new Promise((rs, rj) => {
try {
 return { template_id, ssboe, usecs, user_msg }
catch (err){
return {error_code:1, error_message: 'some msg'}
}

}))

}
```

Comment: Your code in the return is not valid. Please fix it first

Comment: better? its some example.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Awaiting promises is common in JavaScript/typescript.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the `Awaited<T>` type is more of an internal utility type than one that developers should need to reach for. Its main purpose is to recursively unwrap the value of chained or nested promises, which was useful in correctly typing JavaScript APIs like `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, and more.

So you can technically use `Awaited<T>` to unwrap the result type of a Promise like so:

```
type MyPromise = Promise<string>;
type Value = Awaited<MyPromise>; // string
```

However, in my opinion, this is a code smell, and there are better language constructs for extracting or deducing the result type of a `Promise<T>`. Typescript already internally uses `Awaited<T>` in the Promise interface, so there aren't many genuine cases for using it yourself.

As for your example, I'm not sure what you mean by "properly implement" it, or why you would need to use the `Awaited<T>` type. The only problem I can see with your code is that you don't use the "resolve" and "reject" functions to fulfill the Promise, and including `Error` in your result type is also generally considered a code smell. It should look something like:

```js
export function Heartbeat(usecs: number, ssboe: number): Promise<Response> {
    return new Promise((rs, rj) => {
        try {
            return rs({ ssboe, usecs, user_msg: "", template_id: 0 });
        } catch (err) {
            return rj({ error_code: 0, error_message: "" });
        }
    });
}
```

Currently, the reason TypeScript doesn't let you specify the reject/exception type as `Error` is because exceptions can propagate deep from within a promise's execution. So at design time, the type checker can't guarantee the caught exception will be of type `Error`, and besides very trivial examples, neither can the developer.